# Install latest Java version on Linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to install the latest version of Java in my Linux machine, but I am unable to do so.

Steps I followed:

1. Downloaded the latest Java tar ball.
2. Copied into /usr/lib/jvm  and untared it.
3. Adding in to environment variable (`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/javm/jdk1.7.0_80, export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`).
4. When I try to change the default Java version, the installed one is
   not coming (`$ update-alternatives –-config java`).

How do I resolve this? I have followed many links, but nothing helps.

Comment: Look carefully for typos. Your JAVA_HOME seems to contain one. Also, your distribution probably has packages for Java. That might be easier.

Comment: You should ask this on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com)

Comment: *"latest java"* ... "`jdk1.7.0_80`" ... the latest Java version is Java 7?

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to "install" the new Java software to `/etc/alternatives/`, in order to select it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/javm/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/bin/java 2000
```